# Golang задачка по циклам на проверку совпадения цифр в двух числах

Tags: golang, циклы

Даны два числа. Определить цифры, входящие в запись как первого, так и второго числа.
Программа получает на вход два числа. Гарантируется, что цифры в числах не повторяются. Числа в пределах от 0 до 10000.
Программа должна вывести цифры, которые имеются в обоих числах, через пробел. Цифры выводятся в порядке их нахождения в первом числе.
Ввод:
564 8954
Вывод:
5 4

код:

`

```
var a, b, c, d int
fmt.Scan(&a, &b)

for a > 0 {
    d = a % 10
    a = a / 10
    c = b
    for  c > 0 {
        if c % 10 == d {
            fmt.Println(d, " ")
        }
        c = c / 10
    }
}
fmt.Println("\n")
```

`

Выводится 4 5, как изменить порядок проверки, вывода?

Comment: постарайтесь давать вопросам заголовки, которые отражают именно ту проблему, с которой вы столкнулись (в данно случае - как изменить порядок вывода или проверки), а не описывать там задачу, которые вы решаете.

Answer (score 0):

1. Перевести оба числа в строку и проверять наличие каждой цифры из первого числа во втором.

или

2. Делать, как у вас, но заносить результат в массив, потом вывести массив в обратном порядке.

или

3. Заносить каждую найденую цифру в строку с результатом, но присоединять не с конца, а с начала.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать функцию, которая "развернет" оба числа перед началом циклов. В этом способе есть косяк, что при реверсе числа, заканчивающегося на ноль, он этот ноль потеряет. Но для примера в задаче (564 8954) прокатит, вывод будет верный ;)

```
func reverse_int(n int) int {
    new_int := 0
    for n > 0 {
        remainder := n % 10
        new_int *= 10
        new_int += remainder
        n /= 10
    }
    return new_int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно с самого начала делать не обратный перебор:

```
package main

import "fmt"
func main() {
    var x int
    var y int
    var k int
    fmt.Scan(&x)
    fmt.Scan(&y)
    for j:=1000; x/j>=0; j=(j/10){
        if(x/j==0){
            continue
        }
        k=(x/j)%10
        for i:=1000; y/i>=0; i=(i/10){
            if(y/i==0){
                continue
            }
            if (k==(y/i)%10){
                fmt.Print(k," ")
            }
            if i==1{
                break
            }
        }
        if j==1{
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто у первого числа берешь цифры с начала, а у другого с конца и выводишь цифру первого числа.

```
 package main
    import "fmt"
    func main(){
        var a, b, x , y int
        fmt.Scan(&a, &b)
        j:=10000
        for a > 0{
            x = a / j
            a = a % j
            y = b
            for y > 0 && x > 0{
                if y%10 == x {
                    fmt.Print(x, " ")
                    
                }
                y = y/10
            }
            j = j/10
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {

```
var (
    sum  string
    a, b int
)
for true {
    fmt.Println("Enter two nums 0 <= num <= 10000")
    fmt.Scan(&a, &b)
    if a < 0 || a > 10000 || b < 0 || b > 10000 {
        fmt.Println("Enter correct nums")
        continue
    } else {
        break
    }
}
for _, n := range strconv.Itoa(a) {
    for _, k := range strconv.Itoa(b) {
        if n == k {
            sum += string(n) + " "
        }
    }
}
fmt.Println(sum)
```

}

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).